# Laravel 5 premature breakage session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I got a problem with a random session expire in Laravel 5. I watched a lot of discussion on this subject, but no one solution does not work.

While I'm on the site and going through the pages, particularly on the page personal account, there is breakage of session and then redirect to the specified in the **app/Http/Middlevare/Authenticate.php** file path. Also deletes all by my other session variables. My **SESSION_DRIVER** is **'file'**, but others drivers has the same problem. There is some of my configs in **session.php**:

- 'lifetime' => 120
- 'expire_on_close' => false
- 'encrypt' => false
- 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions')
- 'connection' => null
- 'table' => 'sessions'
- 'lottery' => [2, 100]
- 'cookie' => 'laravel_session'
- 'path' => '/'
- 'domain' => null
- 'secure' => false
- 'http_only' => true

Comment: Does this happen locally on your machine or on some server/hosting?

Comment: it happens on the server, I use the Hetzner server for my project

Comment: Ask them if they use load balancer or if they sync the session throughout their servers. If they don't your session will be lost or conflicted, because different machines might process your request depending on your hosting plan. The solution would be to use another session driver for example **redis** or **memcache** which will store the whole session in one place.

Comment: @TheFallen, I have the dedicated server, so I haven't any support =) I configure it by myself, and I'm new to server administration. If you give me some advice on setting up the server I will be very grateful to you =)

Comment: Well like I said try to use redis or memcache for session driver. The only reason for your session to randomly disappear might be the storage, so ditching the file driver would be my best guess for solving the problem.

Comment: @TheFallen, thanks for your answers, I'll try it!